# How to make image of the button visible even after it is pressed in sencha

Tags: sencha-touch

I am using sencha to create an application.
In this i am using button which for which i have defined the icons.

ex:

- Sencha

  {
   xtype:'button',
    height:30,
    width:30,
    cls:'btn'
  }
- CSS

  .btn
  {
    background:"../../resources/img/hosrse.png";
  }

But when i am clicking on the button the image is disappearing. What to do to keep the image appear even after pressing the button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to overload the .x-button-pressed rule, i.e.

```
.btn.x-button.x-button-plain,
.btn.x-button.x-button-plain.x-button-pressed {
    background:"../../resources/img/hosrse.png";
}
```